# Method AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication do not working

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c, .net-7.0

I'm using AzureB2C to authenticate my .net7 API.
When I change the obsolete code:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2CAuthentication", options));
```

To this new code, using the new library Microsoft.Identity.Web:

```
        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(configuration,
            "AzureAdB2CAuthentication");
```

The authentication flow stops working, I didn't change any configurations on B2C instance.

***`appsettings.json`***

```cs
"AzureAdB2CAuthentication": 
{ 
 "Instance": "<instanceUrl>", 
 "Domain": "<domain>", 
 "TenantId": "<tenantId>", 
 "ClientId": "<clientId>", 
 "SignedOutCallbackPath": "<path>", 
 "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "<policyId>" 
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what this configuration looks like?

Comment: Looks like this:

  "AzureAdB2CAuthentication": {
    "Instance": "<instanceUrl>",
    "Domain": "<domain>",
    "TenantId": "<tenantId>",
    "ClientId": "<clientId>",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "<path>",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "<policyId>"
  },